# Adding and removing divs dynamically in Vue JS component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am new to VueJS and now I face a problem I just can't figure out. I want to add and remove  elements dynamically by clicking buttons. How do I get this to work, so I can remove a specific div and not always the last one I added. I played around with this a lot and now I even get an error [Vue warn]: You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function. I likely shouldn't set div=index and instead work with div.id etc. Hope someone can help me out with this. Thanks.

https://jsbin.com/zuquwej/edit?html,js,output

```
  <div id="app">

    <div
      v-for="(div, index) in divs"
      :key="div.id"
      :div="div=index"
    >
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">Div {{div}}</div>
      </div>

      <button
        class="btn btn-danger"
        @click="deleteRow(index)"
      >Delete</button>

    </div>

    <button
      class="btn btn-success"
      @click="addRow"
    >Add row</button>

  </div>
```

```
const app = new Vue({

  el: '#app',

 data() {
    return {
      div: 0,
      divs: []
    };
  },

  methods: {
    addRow() {
      this.divs.push({
        div: this.div
      });
      console.log(this.divs);
    },
    deleteRow(index) {
      this.divs.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }

})
```

Comment: What's the `div = index` bit supposed to achieve?

Comment: An unnecessary way to eventually get and store the index value in the divs array...I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should store an index each object you generate and store into component's `divs` property. By the way, unlike array index, it won't change if you splice an element from this array. Here is a working example:

```html
<div
      v-for="div in divs"
      :key="div.id"
    >
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">Div {{ div.name }}</div>
      </div>

      <button
        class="btn btn-danger"
        @click="deleteRow(div.id)"
      >Delete</button>

    </div>
```

```js
const app = new Vue({ 
  el: '#app',

  data() {
    return {
      index: 0,
      divs: []
    };
  },

  methods: {
    addRow() {
      this.divs.push({
        id: this.index,
        name: 'div' + this.index,
      });
      this.index++;
    },
    deleteRow(index) {
      this.divs.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }

})
```

Comment: Thank you @Shizzen83, this helped me a lot and now everything works fine. Regarding the removal of a specific div I now changed it to deletedRow(id) and `this.divs = this.divs.filter(d => d.id !== id);`

Comment: Yes, well done :) I suggest you using Lodash (and specifically `lodash/fp`) to achieve this kind of tasks https://gist.github.com/jfmengels/6b973b69c491375117dc

Comment: to delete specific div I add this
1- get the div index in divs array
const divIndex = this.divs.findIndex((div) => div.id === id);
2- then splice it
this.divs.splice(divIndex, 1);